# Why is my canvas not clearing correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently working on a little experimental project with HTML5 Canvas.

Basically, at the moment i'm just trying to make the canvas clear as expected. The only thing that my code does as the moment is generate a lines that are broken in the middle. However, at the moment i'm trying to make one line, and then remove that line and add another line at another different position without showing the first line.

I would of thought that this code would work:

```
poles(20); // this number is the x position at which the line (pole) will be generated
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
poles(140)
```

In all technically, this should show only the second pole because the canvas should have been cleared after the first pole was generated. But hit still shows both.

When I tried only:

```
poles(20);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

The canvas was blank which told me that the clearing worked correctly.

I tried one more thing:

```
poles(20);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
setTimeout(function () {
    poles(140)
}, 1000);
```

In this case, both poles did show up but not until after 1 second which told me that the `poles` function is causing both to be generated again even though the function doesn't loop:

```
function poles(x) {
    var bottomH = getRandomInt(20, 180)
    // using seperate rectangles will make a break
    rect(40, 220 - bottomH, x, 0); // first section of line
    rect(40, bottomH, x, HEIGHT - bottomH); // second section of line        
}
```

I hope someone can explain to me how come my `poles` function is cause both of the poles to reappear.

You can view the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/zswr6hww/4/show/).
For Reference, the main code is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    WIDTH = canvas.width,
    HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function rect(w, h, x, y) {
    ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
    ctx.fill();
}

function poles(x) {
    var bottomH = getRandomInt(20, 180); // determine where the line break will be
    rect(40, 220 - bottomH, x, 0);
    rect(40, bottomH, x, HEIGHT - bottomH);
}

poles(20);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
setTimeout(function () {
    poles(140)
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with your `rect` function. Specifically, with the usage of the `.rect()` member of the `ctx`.  The rect member creates a path, which you then fill with `ctx.fill()` - only problem is, it doesn't close the path, so it remains open and is added to when the second call to poles comes along.

You can either close the path before exiting the `rect` function, or even more simply, avoid paths altogether by defining and filling the rectangle in a single call, by using `ctx.fillRect`.

The following change makes the code function as expected:

```
function rect(w, h, x, y) 
{
//    ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
//    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about closing the Path. You are totally right c: Thank you. And I will take your advice and just avoid it!

Comment: One correction: not *close* the path (rect sub-paths can't be closed by definition - no open ends to close). Use **`beginPath()`** before any new path operation (after filling/stroking).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg - thanks Ken. Good catch, re: use of `beginPath()`